# Open problems about Morita and derived invariants

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

> Are there properties of rings of which one does not know whether they are Morita or derived invariances?

For a recent such example for Morita invariance, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869314004669 .

One can restrict also to special classes of rings such as finite dimensional algebras.

For derived equivalences it is for example an open problem whether having infinite dominant dimension is a derived invariant, see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11856-016-1327-4 .

Comment: Certainly "yes" but your real question is "what are the unknown ones" right?

Comment: Interesting related reading: https://mathoverflow.net/q/124856/19965

Comment: I remember reading in Carl Faith's books that it is unknown if the Ore condition is Morita invariant, but those books are pretty old. I haven't found anything about a resolution to it yet.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I ask about the unknown ones.