# semilocal total quotient ring whose J(R) is not zero

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I am interested in rings in which every non-unit is a zero divisor. Can you give me an example of such a ring that also has FINITELY many maximal ideals (semilocal), and whose Jacobson radical is not zero?
Thanks

P.S. There is a question about this [Rings in which every non-unit is a zero divisor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42647/rings-in-which-every-non-unit-is-a-zero-divisor) but none of the answers satisfy my constrains.

Edit: I am sorry I haven't specified - I am not interested in an example that is a finite ring, or the one that is local (and both the examples in comments are in this category). Also Artinian rings won't do.

Comment: Try $k[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$ where $k$ is a field.

Comment: Or any nonreduced finite ring, such as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ if $n$ is not squarefree (this *is* mentioned in the question referred to).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = k[x_1,x_2, \ldots]$ be the polynomial ring over a field $k$ in infinitely many variables and let $\mathfrak{m} = \langle x_1,x_2,\ldots \rangle$. Then $(A / \mathfrak{m}^2)^2$ satisfies all of your conditions.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this ring has infinitely many maximal ideals...

Comment: If $R = (A / \mathfrak{m}^2)^2$ then $J(R) = \mathfrak{m}R$ has square zero, and $R / J(R) \cong (A / \mathfrak{m}) \times (A / \mathfrak{m}) \cong k \times k$. This ring, and hence $R$ itself, has precisely two maximal ideals. 